# Load other css by using a different URL on the same page

Tags: css, url, styles

I have a CMS website and in an overview page I have the possibility to look at a page (popup) and a link with also a popup of the same page but with an other style, I don't want to duplicate the pages so I really like to load a different css file just by changing the URL with something like the .html?xxx.

This page: 
http://www.xxx.com/pdf/test1.html

Need to load a different css file when I go to url: test1.html?css=blabla
Or is it possible to do this with javascript?

Any help is appreceated

Comment: Can you say that what do you want?

Comment: Sure, it's possible (but you'll ideally need a server-side language to do it)

Comment: I don't know how to be clearer on this. I think using javascript will be the best method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    if(window.location.href.indexOf('?pdf=true') > -1) {

        document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"http://www.site.com/pdf-style.css\" />");
    }
    document.close(); 
</script>
```

When use xxxx.html?pdf=true the css is being loaded :))

Bit lame to -1 my post thow...